# iOS jquery .on click with library 1.8.3

Tags: jquery, ios, touch

For some reason I can't get this event to work on my iPhone.

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-default')){
        $(".upload").show();
    }
});
```

It works with bind, but now that I'm loading things after the dom loads I need to use .on

Is there a touch event or something to trigger the touch events.

Comment: Try this: `$(document).on('click touchstart', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {`

Comment: I have posted it as an answer for the reference of other users too. Feel free to mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    $(".upload").show();
});
```

No need to check this `$(this).hasClass('ui-state-default')`, since your click event will only work for the elements having the `.ui-state-default`, which means that `this` has a class called `ui-state-default` already. So, on click of it, you can simply show `.upload` element.

Comment: @Blynn: Nice app. You got the 20th like from me. Cheers :)

Comment: As a sidenote you should stop propagation within your script. It is possible both events will fire depending on the nature of the element with this specific class on it, and that could cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.ui-state-default', function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-default')){
        $(".upload").show();
    }
});
```